# pdflatex vs lualatex papersize layout problem

Tags: luatex, geometry, paper-size

The next code produce a a6 format paper with `pdflatex` that fit well, but with `lualatex` the layout is a6 on a a4 paper sheet.

Passing `a6paper` option to geometry package doesn't solve the problem.

How have a correct papersize.

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

Hello word !

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geometry has not been updated for the changes in lualatex (where they removed some `\pdf...` variables). Add this before `\documentclass`:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
```

Comment: Forget about this one... I'll accept in 3 minutes.

Comment: Is `geometry` not maintained anymore?

Comment: If you load `graphicx.sty` and/or `xcolor.sty` **before** `geometry.sty` your MWE works as expected. Of course, you have to be using `graphicx.sty` and/or `xcolor.sty` in the first place ;)... (I use them practically all the time). So far, I have found no downside to this workaround.

Comment: luatex85 is not needed for geometry version 5.7 released yesterday

Comment: @AlexG https://github.com/davidcarlisle/geometry

Comment: @David Thanks! Yet another pkg of which you have become the maintainer?